# dynamic button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a dynamic button. But the value of all buttons is the same. what should I do for this? I want every one to have different values.

[image: Example image]

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
  var r = $('<input type="button" value="new button" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px;"/>');
  $("#sth").append(r);

  $("#sth").css({
    width: '300px',
    'padding-top': '10px',
    'padding-bottom': '10px',
    'padding-left': '10px'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sth"></div>
```

Comment: so what name do you want

Comment: `value="new button'+i+'" `

Comment: What should be those name ? Simply `New button 1`, `New button 2`,... ?

Comment: @onur you can create buttonArray which has button names

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. I created a [mcve] from your code but you do need to explain what the expected result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index to change the value of each button. See if this helps.

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
        var r = $('<input type="button" value="new button ' + i + '" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px;"/>');
        $("#sth").append(r);
}
$("#sth").css({ width: '300px', 'padding-top': '10px', 'padding-bottom': '10px', 'padding-left':'10px' });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='sth'></div>
```

Comment: It's clearly already answered in the comments to a question not worth answering

Comment: Buddy, I didn't check comment when I begin answering this question. My screen was in code mode, so couldn't know if it was answered or not. I appreciate you had answered before me.

Comment: You are aware you are setting the sth's CSS in every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to put only just distinct names there you just play with the index

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
var r = $('<input type="button" value="Button_"' + i + '"style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px;"/>');
$("#sth").append(r);

  $("#sth").css({
    width: '300px',
    'padding-top': '10px',
    'padding-bottom': '10px',
    'padding-left': '10px'
  });
}
```

It will result like this[image]

or else you can use a custom array for keeping some names with corresponding indices

```
    var arr = ['apple','orange','pineapple','tomato','grapes','ginger','ghee','sugar','milk','brinjal','potato'],name;
for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    name = arr[i] ? arr[i] : 'button_'+ i; 
    var r = $('<input type="button" value="' + name + '"style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px;"/>');
    $("#sth").append(r);

      $("#sth").css({
        width: '300px',
        'padding-top': '10px',
        'padding-bottom': '10px',
        'padding-left': '10px'
      });
    }
```

Its result will be like above
[image]

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - also move the CSS outside the loop

Answer (score -1):

You should change your string here :

```
$('<input type="button" value="new button" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px;"/>');
```

For something like this :

```
$('<input type="button" value="new button-' + i + '" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px;"/>');
```

So you will have : new button-1, new button-2 ....
Hope that help